# What is the cause of Cannot merge node using null property value for uuid in Spring Data Neo4j starter and OGM SessionFactory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Apparently this is a common exception but, all the questions asked here seem to be related to `CSV` hence, why this question.

I have a `domain` object that make use of `uuid` as unique id and is declared as follow

```
@NodeEntity(label = "TNODE")
public class TestNode {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class) 
    @Convert(UuidStringConverter.class)
    private UUID uuid;

    private String name; 

    @Relationship(type = "TEST_REL_IS", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING) private TestNodeTarget testTarget;

    public TestNode() {}
    public TestNode(String name, TestNodeTarget target) {
        this.name = name; 
        this.testTarget = target;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

And the `TestNodeTarget` is as follow

```
@NodeEntity(label = "TNODE_TARGET")
public class TestNodeTarget {
    private Long id; 
    private String name;

    public TestNodeTarget() {}
    public TestNodeTarget(String name) {
        this.name = name; 
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

I am using `Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE` with `sprng-boot-data-neo4j` starter which pulls down `neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.0`, `neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.1.0`, `neo4j-ogm-api-3.1.0` and The mysterious `neo4j-java-driver-1.5`.

I am using the `Neo4j OGM SessionFactory` to build my own generic DAO layer instead of Spring Data Repository that restricts me from

- Single Repository for all domains (i.e. loadById(classType, id))
- Run custom cypher queries
- Some other reasons I don't remember

### Issue

I am able to perform `CREATE`, `READ` and `DELETE` operations. The `PUT` operations with following assumptions

1. Previously created `tn:TestNode`, `t1:TestNodeTarget` and `t2:TestNodeTarget`
2. The `tn` node has a relationship with `t1` node
3. Retrieve `tn` node, `t1 & t2` nodes
4. Change the `tn` node relationship to `t2` from `t1`
5. Call `session.save`

The exception is

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Cannot merge node using null property value for uuid
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil.newNeo4jError(ErrorUtil.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageDispatcher.handleFailureMessage(InboundMessageDispatcher.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:432)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:396)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:83)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:35)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.MessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageDecoder.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1336)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1127)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1162)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
```

### Questions

1. What is the root cause of the error `Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Cannot merge node using null property value for uuid` message? The node `uuid` value is not null.
2. How do `bolt-driver` and `neo4j-java-driver` communicate with each other? I was surprised to see `neo4j-java-driver`.
3. Since I am using `Neo4j OGM` in favour of Spring Data's `Repository` then can I ditch the `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j`? If yes, what happens to the `@Transactional` and transaction management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Using a `UUID` field annotated with `@Id` is not a replacement to `private Long id` field (or is it?). Add the `id` field to the class and the exception disappears.

I couldn't wait and decided to debug this issue myself and share my findings

### Transaction

At first, the `PUT` operation worked (without the `private Long id` field) without exception but failed to delete the old relationship and based on this [Github issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/477) I wrapped the operations in `@Transactional` and I got the exception. Some progress.

In `ORM` context, the above would work fine. In other words, I can `retrieve` the entity from `@Transactional` annotated service layer, make necessary changes in a `non-transactional` layer and then `persist` the entity using another service layer method that is annotated with `@Transactional`. For `OGM` you gotta do it all in same transaction layer. Hum!

### The exception

As shown in the question above, the `TestNode` entity makes use of `UUID` as follow

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class) 
@Convert(UuidStringConverter.class)
private UUID uuid;
```

I had to update the `TestNode` class to include a

```
private Long id;
```

And after this the `PUT` operation works as expected and the old relationship gets removed.

### Confusions

Why lack of `private Long id;` only cause exception during update? Why not when you `retrieve`, `delete`, or `create` the entity?